# Python, pycharm install scrapy error

Tags: python

I got this error:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\emrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe'.
```

Comment: Add some information about what are you trying to do.

Comment: I want to add the scrapy library to pycharm. But I am getting such an error

Comment: You have the `scrapy` installed?

Comment: I get an error when trying to install

Comment: http://prntscr.com/eqtxez

Answer (score 0):

Follow the error and install `Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition`.

Comment: I have ms vs 2010